# Аналог CRON на PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Да, google был просмотрел. Возможно плохо, но всё таки:
есть файлик sync.php,
есть mysql,
Нет доступа к crontab и т.п.

как бы создать аналог cron на чистом php (мб + mysql) без использования утилит linux?

Условия: самый тухлый шаред-хостинг, с отсутствием возможности подключения модулей веб-сервера, да и вообще без доступа к нему. Есть phpMyAdmin.

Comment: создаёте скрипт, в котором есть бесконечный цикл и запускаете его.

Comment: А если веб-сервер перезапустится? Цикл умрёт. Поэтому и демоны - не совсем вариант.

Comment: А точно не обойтись без PHP? подумайте - возможно, задача решается чисто SQL-процедурой, а у MySQL как раз есть свой собственный планировщик...

Comment: "А если веб-сервер перезапустится? Цикл умрёт. Поэтому и демоны - не совсем вариант. "...ну так можно же сконфигурировать веб-сервер, чтобы при старте выполнял скрипт, и запускал вашего демона

Comment: Демон работает независимо от веб-сервера. Но да, если он умрёт, то это навсегда. Поэтому не давайте ему упасть. Если утечек памяти в скрипте не будет, то жить он будет долго и счастливо.

Comment: Это всё ок, хорошо. ну вот допустим у меня самый тухлый shared хостинг, где даже mod_rewrite  включить проблемно...и никаких кронов и в помине нет. Да, есть phpmyadmin